# Why do I keep getting a blank screen when i install a Xamarin.Forms app apk on my phone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When i run my application in the emulator for android on visual studios it works fine. When i try and run it as an installed apk on my phone, i only get a blank screen, like a content page with no UI elements not even a lable. I tried building for different API versions still the same. Even the basic xamarin.forms template, wont show any UI elements on my phone. I'm new to xamarin.forms so any help will be appreciated.
here is the androidManifes.xaml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my android options
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1r7H.png)

Comment: Can you debug the app straight from VS to your phone with ADB and share the log here?

Comment: Post your "Android Options" in project properties for debug and release configrations.

Comment: What would i need to do that?

Comment: Connect your phone using USB and then select your Phone name from the devices list and run the App. Put breakpoints as and where needed and debug.

Comment: @RubenvanNiekerk You can take a look [Set Up Device for Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development),This article explains how to setup an Android device and connect it to a computer so that the device may be used to run and debug Xamarin.Android applications.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to occur in some versions of xamarin when you are trying to install the signed apk in debug mode. In order to solve it change to release mode, compile the solution and install the `.apk` file you will find in the android release folder.